# Refresh the Form in windows application using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Again I'm in need of ur help.Here is the process

1.I Have one form with a textbox

2.In keyDown event While pressing F1 an another form opens.

3.In the second form,i have a richtextbox.I want to edit tat richtextbox and pass that 
value to form1's textbox while clicking a button in form2.

Form1 Code:

```
private void Export_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "hai hello welcome to chennai";
    }private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode ==Keys.F1)
        {
            rchbox rch = new rchbox();
            rch.Show();
            rch.richTextBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

Form2 Code:

```
public rchbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Export ex = new Export();
    Class1 c = new Class1();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.txt = richTextBox1.Text;
        ex.textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
        ex.textBox1.Refresh();
        ex.Refresh();
        ex.Invalidate();
       // ex.textBox1.Invalidated();
        this.Close();

    }
```

I have found the problem that the form1 is not refreshed.i have even tried by calling refresh method.
Can any one tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a brand new instance of the `Export` form, which you never show.
You aren't changing the existing instance.

Instead, you need to change the second form to take the existing `Export` instance as a constructor parameter.

Comment: i'm already showing tat form.if i show it again the process already exists will once again start.i no need to start it from first.better tell me an idea to refresh the textbox of export

Comment: @user1668052: Wrong.  `new Export()` is a **second** copy of the Export form, which you don't show.

Comment: @user1668052: You need to change the second form to take the existing Export instance as a constructor parameter.